# Improve compass heading calculations using 9DoF IMU

Tags: c, accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer, imu

I've been implementing a compass using raw data from a [ICM-20948](https://github.com/sparkfun/OpenLog_Artemis/blob/main/SENSOR_UNITS.md#ICM-20948-IMU) IMU. It provides me with Accelerometer, Gyro, and Magnetometer data, but I've been using only Accelerometer and Magnetometer data to calculate heading like this:

```
float computeHeading(double mag_x, double mag_y, double mag_z, double accel_x, double accel_y, double accel_z)
{
    const vec3 vector_mag = create_vec3(mag_x, mag_y, mag_z);
    const vec3 vector_down = create_vec3(accel_x, accel_y, accel_z);
    const float scale = dot_vec3(vector_mag,vector_down) / dot_vec3(vector_down, vector_down);
    const vec3 vector_north = sub_vec3 (vector_mag , scale_vec3(scale, vector_down));
    return atan2(vector_north.x, vector_north.y) * 180 / M_PI;
}
```

It works well when doing the YAW rotation, but everything falls apart once I PITCH or ROLL the IMU for just a couple of degrees. [Here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/88707) is where I got the algorithm from.

Is there any way I can make the calculation more robust? (maybe using gyro)

Comment: Stick to `double` and don't switch to `float` unless you have a very good reason why you can't use `double`. Why is `scale` using `float`? The `atan2` returns a `double`, why do you return a `float`?

Comment: @Filip Vuković, Protect against division by 0 due to `dot_vec3(vector_down, vector_down) == 0`.

Comment: Thank You for Your comments. I will stick to double (it's a bad habit of mine to always use floats) and I will check if that dot product is 0, although it's only possible if that vector is a zero vector